# Determining the branch of the complex argument

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I am working on a complex analysis problem and I am stuck at a particular section. Basically, we are given a region in which the argument of a complex number, $\arg(z)$, is defined, and its value at a given point. We are then asked to find the argument of other complex numbers based on this information.

The point in which I am stuck is when working in $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{re^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}: r \geq 0\}$ and I am given $\arg(1)=0$, and I need to find $\arg(i)$. I thought that the "origin line" for measuring the angle of a complex number in this set was the reflection through the origin of the removed line: $\{re^{i(\frac{\pi}{4} + \pi)}: r \geq 0\}$. From there, I calculated the argument of 1 from this line:

$$
\arg(1) = \frac{3\pi}{4} + 2\pi n \quad , n\in \mathbb{Z}
$$
and imposed $\arg(1) = 0$ to find $n$, but I get nonsense: $n = -3/8$.

Where is the flaw in this argument? Perhaps I am wrong when defining the argument in $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{re^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}: r \geq 0\}$ this way? By the way, the answer turns out to be $\arg(i) = -\frac{3\pi}{2}$.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really a Euclidean geometry exercise and I would very strongly advise drawing a picture of the Euclidean plane. I'll describe the picture in words.

- Draw the complex plane (i.e. the $x,y$ plane).
- Draw the ray $\{r e^{i \pi/4} : r \ge 0\}$ as a dotted ray, to indicate that it is omitted (i.e. the portion of the line $y=x$ in the first quadrant of the $x,y$ plane).
- Plot the point $1 = 1 + 0i$ (i.e. the point $(1,0)$)
- Plot the point $i = 0+1i$ (i.e. the point $(0,1)$)
- Connect $1$ to $i$ by circular arc, contained in the unit circle, which *misses* the dotted ray (i.e. the portion of the unit circle in the $4^{\text{th}}$, $3^{\text{rd}}$ and $2^{\text{nd}}$ quadrants).
- Let the radian angle vary continuously along that circular arc, from $0$ radians at $1+0i$, to the appropriate radian value at $0+1i$: From $0$ radians at $1+0i$, the arc goes through the 4th quadrant to $-\pi/2$ radians at $0-1i$, then continues through the 3rd quadrant to $-\pi$ radians at $-1+0i$, and finally continues through the 2nd quadrant to $-3\pi/2$ radians at $0+1i$.

So the argument is $-3\pi/2$.

---

By the way, I don't know what you mean by "origin line". However if I may borrow that terminology, the key to this problem is that your "original" ray through $1+0i$ is the positive half of the $x$-axis, and then you spin that ray in the clockwise direction (to avoid the removed ray) until reaching the "final" ray through $0+1i$.

Comment: I see, completely visual. Thank you! I have one doubt though: the effect of removing this line has no implication on how we define the "origin line" by which we measure the angles of complex numbers? Is it still the line $[0, \infty)$?

Comment: I added some words about that point. But if this isn't enough then you'll have to explain your understanding of the "origin line" terminology. It's not standard terminology and I would not like to guess what it means in whatever sources you are using.

Comment: What I mean by "origin line" is that we have chosen the line $[0, \infty)$ to measure angles, but we could have chosen any other line through the origin. It is a completely made up term, I apologise for the confusion.

Comment: Well then, my final paragraph is the best thing I can think of saying. In this problem, the given point $1=1+0i$ defines the "origin ray" (I would avoid the terminology "origin line").

Comment: Again, thank you! Very intuitive explanation.

Comment: The reason the point 1=1+0i defines the ray from which the argument is measured (apart from it being the only non-zero point which is canonically given in the definition of C) is that the argument is the imaginary part of the multi-valued function Log, the "inverse" to the exponential function: if $\mathrm{exp}(z) = w$, then $z = \mathrm{log}(|w|) +i \mathrm{arg}(w)$, where $\mathrm{arg}(w)$ is only defined up to multiples of 2$\pi$, and is the angle $w$ makes with the ray through 1+0i.